# Can't upload my new Apple certificate to AppCenter

Tags: ios, certificate, appcenter

I have a build branch on AppCenter iOS, my certifacte expires and when I'm trying to upoload the new one, an error message appears:

"Oh no, we couldn’t configure your branch!
Provisioning profile "XXXXXXX" includes older version of signing certificate "Apple Distribution: XXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you have to create a new build branch from scratch. First of all deleting the faulty one in menu in the right-upper corner  "Remove build configuration"

[image]